# How to extract uuid from Ramsey\Uuid\Codec\StringCodec?

Tags: php, symfony4

So far, from the following lines

```
$records = $this->entityManager->getRepository(Translation::class)->findBy([], ['id' => 'DESC'], 1, 0);
$uuid = $records[0]->getId();
```

I could get following lines.

```
Ramsey\Uuid\Uuid {#131
  #codec: Ramsey\Uuid\Codec\StringCodec {#86
    -builder: Ramsey\Uuid\Builder\DefaultUuidBuilder {#383
      -converter: Ramsey\Uuid\Converter\Number\DegradedNumberConverter {#390}
    }
  }
  #fields: array:6 [
    "time_low" => "1483fc71"
    "time_mid" => "66e9"
    "time_hi_and_version" => "4e21"
    "clock_seq_hi_and_reserved" => "b9"
    "clock_seq_low" => "50"
    "node" => "c6e9e6405428"
  ]
  #converter: Ramsey\Uuid\Converter\Number\DegradedNumberConverter {#390}
  uuid: "1483fc71-66e9"
}
```

How can I extract `uuid` ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The class implements PHP's `__toString` method, so you can just cast the object to a string:

```
$uuid = (string) $records[0]->getId();
```

Answer (score 0):

With `Ramsey\Uuid\Uuid` you can extract the UUID as a string in serval ways. The base method is `Ramsey\Uuid\Uuid::toString()`, so for your code example like this:

```
$uuid = $records[0]->getId()->toString();
```

For naming conventions there exists some wrapper methods that all calling `Ramsey\Uuid\Uuid::toString()`:

```
Ramsey\Uuid\Uuid::serialize()

Ramsey\Uuid\Uuid::jsonSerialize()
```

But of course you can cast the whole object to string, like @iainn mentioned before.